# Python boto ec2 - How do I wait till an image is created or failed

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I am writing a code to iterate through all available instances and create an AMI for them as below:

```
for reservation in reservations:
    ......
    ami_id = ec2_conn.create_image(instance.id, ami_name, description=ami_desc, no_reboot=True)
```

But how do I wait till an image is created before proceeding with the creation of next image? Because I need to track the status of each ami created.

I know that I can retrieve the state using:

```
image_status = get_image(ami_id).state
```

So, do I iterate through the list of ami_ids created and then fetch the state for each of them? If so, then what if the image is still pending when I read the state of the image? How will I find out if the image creation has failed eventually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to initiate the `create_image` call and then wait until the server-side operation completes before moving on.  To do this, you have to poll the EC2 service periodically until the state of the image is either `available` (meaning it succeeded) or `failed` (meaning it failed).  The code would look something like this:

```
import time
...
image_id = ec2_conn.create_image(instance.id, ...)
image = ec2_conn.get_all_images(image_ids=[image_id])[0]
while image.state == 'pending':
    time.sleep(5)
    image.update()
if image.state == 'available':
    # success, do something here
else:
    # handle failure here
```

Comment: Thanks @garnaat. Just one correction. According to the docs (http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.connection), create_image return the image id, and not the image object.

Comment: You're right.  I looked at the code and saw that it was creating an Image object but missed the fact that it then returns just the ``id`` of that object.  I have corrected the example.  Alternatively, you could just call ``get_all_images`` in a loop if you prefer.

Comment: One more question. So if I have to create an AMI for s store-backed instance, is the process same as above?

Comment: No, its quite a bit more involved.  You actually have to run bundling software on the instance, upload the bundles to S3, and then register the new AMI.  The details are here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html).

Comment: i got error "AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'get_all_images'"

Answer (score 4):

I think the best thing to do is use a waiter, none of the answers above do that:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.ImageAvailable

Answer (score 2):

I use the following snippet to wait for an AMI image:

```
import boto3

def is_image_available(image_id):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    waiter = client.get_waiter('image_available')
    waiter.wait(Filters=[{'Name': 'image-id', 'Values': [image_id]}])
    image = client.describe_images(ImageIds=[image_id])
    if image['Images'][0]['State'] == 'available':
       return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is using boto3, the following would work:

```
import boto3
import time
region = 'us-west-1'
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
def is_image_available(image_id):
    try:
        available = 0
        while available == 0:
            print "Not created yet.. Gonna sleep for 10 seconds"
            time.sleep(10)
            image = client.describe_images(ImageIds=[image_id])
            if image['Images'][0]['State'] == 'available':
                available = 1
        if available == 1:
            print "Image is now available for use."
            return True
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Using this function you should be able to pass the image_id and get the status as true if its available. You can use it in an if condition as follows:

```
if is_image_available(image_id):
# Do something if image is available
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Boto now has the `wait_until_running` method which saves rolling your own polling code:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.wait_until_running

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the exact same question.

Keep updating the image state variable while the state is not running.
At any point if the state is running, break the loop.
You can also check for terminated states or failed states.

```
image = ec2.Image(image_id)
if(image.state == 'pending'):
        print("Waiting for image to be available.")
        while(image.state != 'available'):
            image = ec2.Image(image_id)
        print("Image Available to use")
```

**TIP:**
**Don't wait for images to be available while creating the images.** 
Check for images to be available while creating the instances from those images. It will save you a lot of time because a lot of pending images will be able to concurrently come into the available state.

**If you wait for each image to be available, you are just adding all the creation time to your program.**

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting the error AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'Image'. I will dig deeper and get back

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_waiter`.

```
waiter = client.get_waiter('image_available')

waiter.wait(
    ImageIds=[
        image_id
    ]
)

print('Image availabled')
```

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.ImageAvailable